# How to compare between two cryptographic algorithms in terms of security?

Tags: hash, provable-security

How to compare between two cryptographic algorithms (e.g. SHA-1 and SipHash) in terms of security? That is, how could one prove that algorithm X is more secure than algorithm Y?

Comment: Algorithm security can't be reliably compared on the basis of their _result_ (a value), even for multiple known (or chosen) inputs. Examining results sometime allows to conclude that an algorithm is insecure, not that it is secure

Comment: are you asking if the security of 2 hash algorithms can be compared using only their outputs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this until it is made clear if 1) only the output should be studied (it seems so) and 2) what kind of cryptographic algorithms should be included.

Comment: @Richie
Yes exactly, and Is there another way to do this?(I mean without compared between outputs.)
for example: Siphash and SHA-1

Comment: @SHdotCom: I've edited your question to clean up the grammar a bit, and to include some information from your comment above. However, if you'd like to see it reopened, it would help if you could edit it yourself to *clearly* answer Maarten's questions above (and to correct any mistakes I might have accidentally introduced). In particular, based on your comments, and the use of the word "hash" in the original question, I'm *assuming* that you're specifically asking about hash algorithms, but it would be good for you to explicitly state that.

Comment: Note that SipHash does not aim to be a collision resistant hash. It only aims for preimage resistance and for being PRF, which only requires collisions to be difficult to find if the attacker doesn't know the key. It has a very small output size. SHA-1 on the other hand tried to be collision resistant, but has since fallen to advancing cryptoanalyis.

Comment: This was flagged for reopening, but I don't see how the recent changes are substantial enough make it more clear what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR, you don't.

At this point, we have algorithms we believe are unbroken by current adversaries. For hashing, this includes the SHA-2 family of hashes, SHA-3, BLAKE2b and others. For authentication, we have the HMAC family of functions, the UMAC family of functions, Poly1305, and others. For symmetric encryption, we have AES, ChaCha20, and others. For asymmetric encryption, we have RSA, too many elliptic curves to name, and others. For digital signatures, we have RSA, ECDSA, and others.

When used correctly and with appropriate key sizes, all of these algorithms are considered secure. "More" secure without additional context is a mostly meaningless question: none of these algorithms will ever be brute-forced. Some or all of these algorithms may contain flaws in their design which could render them useless or weakened tomorrow, next year, or a century from now. Some or all of these algorithms may never be broken. But there's no way to know which ones will fall into which category until this happens.

In specific contexts, some algorithms may have desirable properties. The so-called [safecurves](http://safecurves.cr.yp.to), for example, are considered more resilient against poorly-written implementations. Block ciphers like AES in virtually all real-world scenarios must be used in a [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) that should be chosen based on  the (not necessarily security-based) requirements of your application.

When misused, *any* algorithm is typically susceptible to catastrophic failure. And unfortunately, virtually any implementation or composition of cryptographic primitives by amateurs (and even, frequently, [professionals](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2011-01-18-tarsnap-critical-security-bug.html)) is prone to mistakes.

The solution to this is to operate at the highest level of abstraction available to you which is provided by respected cryptographers and software developers. Typically, this means [GPG for data at rest, TLS for data in motion](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2009/7/22/if-youre-typing-the-letters-a-e-s-into-your-code-youre-doing.html). These projects have the benefit of many eyeballs, decades of fixing security issues, and reasonably general default choices for algorithms.

If you're not a seasoned cryptographer and you're making a decision about what cryptographic primitive to use, you have already lost.

Comment: Surely it must be possible to implement HMAC and AES securely for a non expert if he would do at least some research on possible attacks and takes the prevention of those attacks in account? (asking since that's what i'm about to do, taking primitives and combining them for a specific purpose)

Comment: The odds are virtually infinitesimal if you're actually implementing the cryptographic primitives yourself. If you're "simply" gluing together existing primitives, the odds are merely severely stacked against you. c.f., every password hashed with MD5/SHA, keys and data appended and hashed for a poor man's (broken) MAC, timing attacks against MACs compared for equality, encrypt-then-mac and mac-and-encrypt schemes, use of unauthenticated encryption modes, IV reuse, `rand`, etc. There are uncountably infinite ways to get it wrong, and precious few to get it right.

Comment: Outside of simply misusing the primitives are flaws derived from not understanding the security model. Replay attacks, for example.

Comment: Yes which is why i've been doinga all of this ***** research just to figure out the attacks i should worry about, the right way to implement it and all the counter measures i would need. It's horrible but i don't think it's impossible. you just need to bury your self in weeks of research.. you don't become a security expert over night but you need to start somewhere.